# XMLSyntaxError: reuse of the xmlns namespace name is forbidden

Tags: xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML string generated in code. I tried to parse this XML string using LXML:

> taskMetaDataXmlDoc = etree.fromstring(ta.GetXMLString())

where ta.GetXMLString() returns the following XML string below:

```
<TaskMetadata xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" seqid="27152" id="27152-SSP" uniqueid="0be1d3a2-bdb9-4896-a2c8-802ed0c64def">
    <Status>Published</Status>
    <AssignedBy/>
    <AssignedTo/>
    <ContentReceived>
        <DateReceived>2023-02-04T06:28:48.0000000+08:00</DateReceived>
        <Remarks/>
    </ContentReceived>
    <Title>[TEST TITLE]</Title>
    <Category xlink:href="Content.xml#r1c1" xlink:type="locator"/>
    <ContentMetadata xlink:href="0be1d3a2-bdb9-4896-a2c8-802ed0c64def-c.xml" xlink:type="locator"/>
    <HistoryMetadata xlink:href="0be1d3a2-bdb9-4896-a2c8-802ed0c64def-h.xml" xlink:type="locator"/>
    <References xlink:href="0be1d3a2-bdb9-4896-a2c8-802ed0c64def-r.xml" xlink:type="locator"/>
    <CreatedDate>2023-02-04T06:28:48.0000000+08:00</CreatedDate>
    <CreatedBy>Scheduler</CreatedBy>
    <LastModifiedDate>2023-02-04T06:28:48.0000000+08:00</LastModifiedDate>
    <LastModifiedBy>Scheduler</LastModifiedBy>
    <InitialPublishedBy>Scheduler</InitialPublishedBy>
    <InitialPublishedDate>2023-02-04T06:28:48.0000000+08:00</InitialPublishedDate>
    <LastPublishedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+08:00</LastPublishedDate>
    <FuturePublishedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+08:00</FuturePublishedDate>
    <FutureUnpublishedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+08:00</FutureUnpublishedDate>
</TaskMetadata>
```

However, the program returns error regarding reuse of XMLNS namespace:

> XMLSyntaxError: reuse of the xmlns namespace name is forbidden, line
> 1, column 58 (, line 1)

I am not particularly good with XML, may I know which part of the XML string is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ta.GetXMLString()` (whatever that is) produces incorrect XML.

---

The `xmlns` prefix is bound to the `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` namespace name. However, that prefix must not be declared in an XML document, and other prefixes (such as `xlink`) must not be bound to the namespace name.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl:

> The prefix **xmlns** is used only to declare namespace bindings and is by definition bound to the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`. It MUST NOT be declared. Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this namespace name, and it MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace. Element names MUST NOT have the prefix `xmlns`.

---

The correct namespace name for [XLink](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/) is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`. If the namespace declaration is changed to `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`, the error goes away.

Answer (score 2):

In the namespace declaration for xlink you have the uri for xmlns:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
```

It should have the uri `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```